# Jmeter how to send multiple default values under __P like ${__P(case_ids,'2211, 2222')}

Tags: jmeter

On my use case I need to send multiple default values under __P like

```
${__P(case_ids,'2211, 2222, ....')}
```

I Tried following cases but no luck:

```
${__P(case_ids,'2211, 2222')}  
${__P(case_ids,"2211, 2222")}
${__P(case_ids,(2211, 2222))}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`${__P}` function call is used for getting a property and not setting it.

You need to set the property using the function:

```
${__setProperty(case_ids,'2211, 2222, ....')}
```